# Problems setting position of CAShapelayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have posted a similar question before but I didn't feel like I got the correct answer. Basically I want to change position of a `CAShapeLayer` to the position of where the touch is located when the touch is moved. I'm using this code that you can see down below. The problem I have is that the animation will work, but it will not be exactly where the touch is located. Instead it will be almost 20 pixels away. Is there any way to fix this?

```
   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches]; 

UItouch *touch = [alltouches objectAtIndex:0];

 CGPoint currentPos = [myTouch locationInView: self];

layer = [self addCircleYellownWithRadius:8 withduration:5 X:currentPos.x Y:currentpos.y];

    }

  -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches]; 

UItouch *touch = [alltouches objectAtIndex:0];

 CGPoint currentPos = [myTouch locationInView: self];
//set layer posotion to touch position
layer.position = CGPointMake(currentPos.x-8,currentPos.y-8);

    }

-(CAShapeLayer *)addCircleYellownWithRadius:(float)radius5 withduration:(float)duration X:(float)x Y:(float)y{
    int radius = (int)radius5;
    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    // Make a circular shape
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                             cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
    // Center the shape in self.view
    circle.position = CGPointMake(x-radius,
                                  y-radius);



    // Configure the apperence of the circle
    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    circle.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth = 5;

    // Add to parent layer
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];

    // Configure animation
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = duration; // "animate over 10 seconds or so.."
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;  // Animate only once..

    // Animate from no part of the stroke being drawn to the entire stroke being drawn
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

    // Experiment with timing to get the appearence to look the way you want
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    // Add the animation to the circle
    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
    CGRect oldFrame = circle.frame;
    circle.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
   circle.frame = oldFrame;
    return circle;
}
```

Comment: Don't repost questions. Instead you should edit and add more information to the original question so that you can get a good answer there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change position of animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230161/change-position-of-animation)